# Build GTK with Windows SDK

Tags: windows, visual-c++, gtk, compilation

how can I compile gtk (itself) with Windows SDK ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building in Visual Studio is still quite a lot of work.  I've done it, but I don't have reproducible steps for you right now.  However, if you have a Linux machine around and are willing to cross-compile I have written up directions on how to build GTK+ for Win32 by cross-compiling.

http://live.gnome.org/Cross%20compiling%20GTK%2B%20for%20Win32

It's also possible to build using MSYS in the command-line on Windows, but that's also a major pain in the ass to get setup.  It's also really, really slow.  Cross-compiling from Linux is, at a minimum, ten times faster.  I'm not 100% sure but it seems to be because if you build using the standard build system then there is a lot of process spawning, which is quite expensive in Win32 compared to Linux.

However, if you want to go this way then install MSYS and pull down the source for glib, atk, cairo, pango, and gtk+.. then try to build using the standard Linux way:
  1/ untar the source tarball
  2/ in the source's root directory do: ./configure
  3/ make

There will undoubtedly be other dependencies that you need to install, such as libpng and libjpeg.

Comment: Do you have take the time to write a tutorial for WinSDK ?

Comment: Not right now, I left the company where I was working on Win32 stuff and I'm doing strictly Linux stuff right now.  I'd like to find time to get back to GTK+ Win32 development, but I don't expect I'll find time soon. :(

Comment: quote: "this page does not exist yet"

Answer (score 3):

Try the HexChat builds. They use Visual Studio 2010 and come with some prepared scripts and solutions to make your life much easier. Oh and you get binary downloads as well.

http://gtk.hexchat.org/

Answer (score 1):

*GTK can be compiled under Cygwin or Microsoft Visual C++.*

Did you try [this](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GTK+ProgrammingTips.html#BASICCONFIGURATION) installation method? Look the *Microsoft Windows* section...

Hope it helps!

Comment: Just because the article is old does not mean it does not work with newer IDEs.

Comment: I've Windows SDK (not IDE), do you have a tutorial for it ?